# C++ Reference Issue

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference

I recently asked a question about the *proper* way to go about creating a class in C++11. I practiced by building a `Tree` class, and I received some wonderful advice. However, I'm having a little trouble understanding why my code is not working.

In particular, I'm having trouble understanding why my `insert` method is not working correctly.

```
template<typename T>
class Tree {
private:
  struct Node {
    T data;
    Node* p_left;
    Node* p_right;
  };

  Node* newNode(T data) { return new Node {data, nullptr, nullptr}; }

  Node* root_;

  //Other functions, etc... (copy constructor and copy assignment operator)

public:
  void insert(T const data) {
    Node*& root = root_;
    while (root != nullptr) {
      root = (data <= root->data ? root->p_left : root->p_right);
    }
    root = newNode(data);
  }

  Tree(): root_(nullptr) {}

  //Other constructors, functions, etc...
};
```

If I create a new `Tree` object, and then populate that object with some data, the object only retains the last piece of inserted data. I know I'm messing up somewhere because of my pointer reference, but I can't figure out where. Any tips in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger to step through your code?

Comment: How do you expect the insert method works? 
What is correct function?

Comment: @Fumu7 You mean what I expect it to do? It checks for an empty area in the tree, and if there is not an empty area, it inserts the data appropriately into the tree so that it creates a BST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues... first, on the very first insert into the Tree, you are not updating the `root`:

```
if (root == nullptr) { return newNode(data); }
```

In fact, you're returning the new node, even though the `insert` function returns `void`.  If you remove that line entirely, the code should work.  If `root` starts out as `nullptr`, the while loop will be skipped and `root` will be updated to a new node.

Second issue is that you're using a reference to a Node pointer, which means that you're moving your Tree's `root_` every time you create a new node. That's not necessarily a good idea.  Personally, I'd write it like this:

```
void insert(T const data) {
    Node** proot = &root_;
    while (*proot != nullptr) {
        proot = (data <= (*proot)->data ? (*proot)->p_left : (*proot)->p_right);
    }
    *proot = newNode(data);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't he be assigning it to `root_`?

Comment: I think that's what he was trying to do by having `root` be a `Node*&` to `root_`.  Caused the other problem, though, because references can't be redirected.

Comment: @Idgabbay Thanks! Yeah, the whole `return newNode(data)` line was a typo. Sorry for the ignorance, but what do you mean "moving [my] Tree's `root_` every time [I] create a new node?" I understand your code, I was just under the impression that double pointers were somehow a bad thing in C++, and that everything should be written as a reference to a pointer when needed. Clearly that is not correct, since my code isn't working.

Comment: Sure thing. In your original implementation of `insert`, you had set `root` as a reference to `root_`. In c++, once a reference is created, that's all it can refer to. Effectively, `root` was just an alias for `root_` at that point. Inside your while loop, you tried to walk down the tree, but instead of moving a temporary pointer down the tree, you were reassigning `root`, hence `root_`, on each step. Once you took a step down the tree, you moved your Tree's `root`, dropping the root of your tree and everything on the other side of it.

Comment: One other thing, pointers to pointers are fine, at least in my opinion. Pointers take a bit of thought, so some people may shy away from them. But seasoned programmers aren't so easily dissuaded. :)

Comment: @Idgabbay Also, I think you mean `Node** proot = &root_;`

Comment: @Idgabbay Ah! Your explanation just made like everything click in my head for some weird reason! Thank you very much!